# strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel for a simple API that routes users from:

```
Route::get('api/v1/mu/{dte?}', 'API\APIController@MUIntervalAPICall');
```

to this controller:

```
public function MUIntervalAPICall(Request $dte)
{
  $date = $dte->dte;
  $element_language = $dte->language;
  $element_customer = $dte->customer;
  $mu_interval = MUInterval::select("SELECT :element_language, :dte, :element_customer, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null"
  , ["element_language" => $element_language, "dte" => $date, "element_customer" => $element_customer])->get()->toArray();
  function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
      foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
          if( is_array($value) ) {
              $key = 'Exception';
              $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
              array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
          } else {
              $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
          }
       }
  }
  $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><muExceptions></muExceptions>');
  array_to_xml($mu_interval,$xml_data);
  $result = $xml_data->asXML();
  return Response::make($result, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

A url I tested (http://localhost:8000/api/v1/mu/2016-02-13?customer=Apple&language=English) gives out this error:

[image]

What causes this? Users would technically put in date?language=&customer= or date?customer= or date?language= or simply just date? but none works.

How would I fetch the values in the URL I mentioned and use it in my query?

Comment: It's to do with your database query

Comment: It seems your query is wrong. Try to do dd($mu_interval) right after your query.

Comment: Do you have any mutator that you set for your model?

Comment: I completed the query..      
$mu_interval = MUInterval::select('element_customer', 'element_contract', 'element_subcontract', 'element_language', 'element_site', 'element', 'src_id', 'src_type_id', 'dte', 'intvl', 'val_src_id', 'exception_name', 'duration_seconds', 'duration_fte'
      , ['element_language' => $element_language, 'dte' => $date, 'element_customer' => $element_customer])->get()->toArray();
I guess my question is. How would I fetch those values in the URL I mentioned and use it in my query?

Answer (score 0):

In response to: **"How would I fetch those values in the URL I mentioned and use it in my query?"**

You're passing the method a `Request` object which you can use to access the data from the request/url.

You can access it using the `input` or `get` methods like this:

```
$element_language = $dte->input('language');

$element_language = $dte->get('language');
```

Further reading here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#accessing-the-request

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_input

I think your code should look like this:

```
public function MUIntervalAPICall(Request $dte)
{
  // get request data
  $date             = $dte->get('dte');
  $element_language = $dte->get('language');
  $element_customer = $dte->get('customer');

  $mu_interval = MUInterval::select("SELECT :element_language, :dte, :element_customer, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null"
  , ["element_language" => $element_language, "dte" => $date, "element_customer" => $element_customer])->get()->toArray();

  // xml stuff
  function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
      foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
          if( is_array($value) ) {
              $key = 'Exception';
              $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
              array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
          } else {
              $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
          }
       }
  }

  $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><muExceptions></muExceptions>');
  array_to_xml($mu_interval,$xml_data);
  $result = $xml_data->asXML();

  // response
  return Response::make($result, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```